# load SWF file on android application

Tags: android, flash

Is this even possible with version 4.4.2 now? I had tried to use webview to load swf file on android application but it does not work. Can someone verify this?

Comment: Unfortunately, Flash is not supported on Android since 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Using Flash in Webviews on Android has not official been supported for a while. It sometimes works on older (4.0 and older) Androidversion where the flash plugin still is installed but the reach is constantly decreasing and I wouldn't recommend using it.

To deploy flash applications on your mobile device you might be able to use AIR though:

http://get.adobe.com/de/air/